# Add a text file in a jar file using powershell

Tags: java, powershell

Has anyone tried to add a text file to a jar file within a jar file using powershell?

For example, I need to add a `sample.txt` file inside a jar file that is inside a jar file.

Is there a creative way to do that in Powershell?

Comment: 'add a file to a jar file, that is inside a jar file' - is that correct? If so that makes this a bit tougher to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

`jar -u file.jar file.txt`

Comment: this worked. but i used this command to help me automate it, javaw.exe -jar -uvf JAR1File.jar\.\JAR2File.jar\.\ sample.txt

Comment: @user2885241 fantastic! I'm glad that could help you a little bit :), don't forget vote!